# Eigenvalues of tridiagonal matrices with repeating/cyclic entries

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics

Consider the matrices $A(n)$, which are $2n \times 2n$ square matrices with entries

$$A(n) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & v & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
v & 0 & w & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & w & 0 & v & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & v & 0 & w & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & w & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots
\end{pmatrix},$$

i.e. those two band diagonals alternate between $v$ and $w$.

I am interested in finding the eigenvalues of these matrices, particularly as we take the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$. Even if there are no exact solutions, maybe there are some other ways of expressing the eigenvalue in an equation form or something. Any signposting to related identities or papers is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is actually easier to deal with the infinite-dimensional matrices, $n \to \infty$. The eigenvalues are basically arbitrary and continuous, just as the ones of $\hat x$ in quantum mechanics which you may represent by [$a + a^\dagger$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators#Matrix_representation) as is well known there.

If $w=0$, then $A= v( \sigma_1\oplus \sigma_1\oplus\sigma_1\oplus\sigma_1\oplus ...)$ with the standard obvious eigenvalues of the Pauli matrix, $\pm 1$, so $\pm v$. Likewise for $v=0$, when $A= w(  0\oplus \sigma_1\oplus\sigma_1\oplus\sigma_1\oplus,...)$ so $\pm w$.

If $w\neq 0\neq v$, then you may take $w$ out of the matrix, and redefine $v/w\mapsto v$, so this becomes a one-parameter problem, 
$$A/w = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & v & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
v & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & v & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & v & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots
\end{pmatrix},$$

To find your bearings, first consider the null eigenvector $(1,0,-v,0,v^2,0,  ...)^T$.

your then appreciate the recursive structure of the eigenvector $\vec E_\lambda=(1,e_2,e_3,e_4, ...)^T $ yielding
$$
\lambda= v e_2 \\
\lambda e_2= v +e_3 \\
\lambda e_3=  e_2+ v e_4 \\
...
$$
which allows finding the eigenvectors for *arbitrary* eigenvalue $\lambda$,
$\vec E_\lambda= (1,~\lambda/v, ~\lambda^2/v-v, ~\lambda (\lambda^2-v^2-1)/v, ~v^2+ \lambda^2(\lambda^2-v^2 -v-1)/v , ...)^T$.

The components $e_m$ should not increase with *m* without bound, which might provide restrictions on the range of allowable eigenvalues $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes I am actually a postdoc working in quantum physics. This Hamiltonian comes from the SSH model that is well known in that community. To calculate the eigenvectors in the infinite case one normally imposes periodic boundary conditions (This would correspond to putting a '1' in the bottom left and upper right corners of your matrix) and then perform a fourier transform so that you have a sum over wavevector 'k' and just a 2x2 matrix which corresponds to the inter-cell degree of freedom. But this kills the "edge states" in the finite case.

Comment: I am exploring if there is a sensible way to capture both the edge states and the continuum of bulk states in one calculation. Anyway please could I have any references for the above? :)

Comment: Also I want to ask for a clarification on "arbitrary and continuous" eigenvalues. The eigenvalues are continuous, but not every number is an eigenvalue. What do you mean by arbitrary? The eigenvalues tend towards two continuous curves, with a finite range of eigenvalues, centered around zero (and with two eigenvalues at zero). I know this from considering the momentum space calculations, and by numerically looking at larger and larger matrices.

Comment: The techniques are from [QM around the clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices).  Do you find restrictions on the eigenvalues in the recursion? Experiment numerically.

Comment: The end of this [Exam](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/exam.pdf) Might help....

Comment: The eigenvalues are in the finite range $[-E_\text{max},+E_\text{max}]$ where $E_\text{max} = \sqrt{v^2 + w^2 + 2vw}$. As the matrix gets bigger they just pack more densely into this range.

Comment: As I suggested, beyond the $w=0$ or $v=0$, $w$ may be factored out of the matrix, so you are left with $\pm |v+1|$. I see the limit in the former case, but not in the explecit answer of the general case. Something must go awry, but, then, again, I took the limit with empty corners. You might adapt the technique. This is only a hint....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104886/discussion-between-tom-and-cosmas-zachos).